# Xcode - renaming project causes problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, rename

I'm currently working on an iphone application. I started working on this from a project template that I found on the internet. Now I want to rename this project. I've successfully renamed the actual project file, folder and the executables and some other stuff, but there is one weird problem. If I try running the application on my iphone device, Xcode refuses to run the executable with the new name - it's trying to run the old one with the old name instead, and thus it happens that it says: "No launchable executable present at path." Which is true, since the path is wrong (wrong name). The weird thing is that it works on the iphone simulator - it's using the correct executable path.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In 3.2.1 on Snow Leopard, there is a "Project->Rename..." menu item that works like a charm. I think it was introduced in 3.2. Shame that it's Snow Leopard only.

Comment: I just attempted this on 3.2.1 and it worked great!  Thanks Colin!

Comment: I am using this script to rename my iOS project. https://github.com/ytbryan/rename

Remember to update your Xcode scheme too.

Answer (score 6):

Renaming Xcode projects can be an absolute nightmare. I personally feel that the best way to "Rename" a project is to create a new Xcode project and copy in the necessary files. I know this seems inconvenient, but it's the most straight-forward approach that I know of.

Currently, renaming a project involves doing a couple of find/replaces on the project, and changing things in the project settings.

I would love if Xcode automated this for you. This is one thing where Eclipse really shines as an IDE.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

http://aplus.rs/cocoa/how-to-rename-project-in-xcode-3x/

I found that to work quite well. Basically, if it's only the executable name you want to change, then open the main project file (the .xcodeproj) as a folder (right click > show package contents), and open the files in there. Then search them for (regular expression this) product.*name, and for each item you find, replace that which is on the right side of the equal sign to what you want your executable file to be named.

I used the text editor smultron for that. Awsome program...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to http://www.tuppis.com/smultron/ -- looks like a nice little editor!

Comment: see Colin's answer, in XCode 3.2.1 there is the "Project->Rename" feature

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add to the above answers that Apple have made this relatively easy in XCode 3.2  - just rename the whole project in Project->Rename and also change the product name in the project settings...

...but after doing that, I still got the 'No launchable executable...' message.

The key is to **restart XCode** after this point (it seems actually necessary to do this), and  everything should be okay.

Just hoping this saves someone a few minutes of confusion!

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you do is just rename the Product. 
Right click Project then Build -> Packaging -> Product Name. Updating this Product Name should  be enough.

Comment: Yeah, it *should* be enough. However, that was what caused this problem in the first place, that Xcode does change the executable name to product name, *BUT* Xcode tries to launch the old executable. If you search through the files I mentioned above, you'll see that product name occurs more than one time, and in those results, you'll see that only one was changed to the name you specified in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Go for this link.

http://www.thohensee.com/?page_id=180

This link not only provides the way of renaming the project. 
It also provides the details of changing executable name.
Try it.
I have implemented it in my project.

Point to be Noted :

Suppose old Name is "Sagar_RK"

& New Name is "SagarRK"

Project will be renamed, but you need to remember following thing.

When you use shared application delegate. You must have to take delegate with old name application delegate.

For example

```
Sagar_RKAppDel *t=(Sagar_RKAppDel*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Try it out.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I had to do, after I thought everything was renamed everywhere was go to:
Project - > Edit Active Target

Then edit the "Product Name" field under Packaging (on the build tab).

Answer (score 1):

Rename project in XCode 4

https://devforums.apple.com/message/378575#378575

Open the Project Navigator
Click on the project name at the top of the tree, tap again and rename box should appear
Review changes - note it will try and change all text everywhere so unselect them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial from phonegap on renaming projects seems pretty good.  It seems to point out all the areas that need a change.  I don't think it matters whether or not you're renaming a phonegap project or a normal project.

[phonegap tutorial](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Replacing-All-References-to-PhoneGap-to-Reflect-Your-App%27s-Name)

Comment: Thanks, I found this useful for renaming an Xcode project under version control where "Project->Rename..." was causing problems.  Not sure why this answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found helped me:
http://drjunker.org/2008/04/10/xcode-rename-project-and-application-change-copyright-and-version-number/. Notice the comment by John Beatty (jcb) - it's an important addition to the steps described in the post.
And this is an [in-depth post](http://arustisha.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/on-the-renaming-of-xcode-projects/) explaining the various kinds of clones you'd want to make, and how to do them. Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is your Project name in XCode4. Simply change the name and press Enter. It works exactly like old XCode version (Project->Rename)...

!! Enjoy !! :)

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions made my project work after I renamed it using Muzammil's suggestion (the so-called correct way of doing it). It's a shame that Apple cannot rename a project that their own tools created.
Why not remove all ways of renaming of a project if not even Apple can do it?... shame on Apple!

I renamed my project which had versioned xcdatamodels and trashed a lot of work... I'm still trying to make it build!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6.3. I think you just need to make "New Scheme" in a place where you can select the device. Then save it and the project should be run on the device as well as on the simulator.

The following screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not to be negative but the one thing about XCode that sucks is all the bugs.   I'm hoping XCode 4. Is a total rewrite and thus more stable.   At best some of the XCode releases have amounted to betas.

In any event you have good responses to your question.   Venting.

Dave